# Can I build several connected roads on the same turn?

Tags: catan

If I have enough resources to build several roads, can I build them connected to each other on the same turn without any other of my settlements or roads to connect to them (excluding the first road)?

For example, if I have enough resources to build four more roads and get Longest Road, can I build a long chain of roads that only connect to each other (excluding the first road)?

If I have enough resources to build one or more roads and a settlement, can I build them connected to each other on the same turn without any other settlements or roads to connect to them (excluding the first road)?

For example, if I have enough resources to build a road and a settlement, but cannot build a settlement without breaking the Distance Rule, can I build a road to be farther away from other settlements and then build my settlement only connected to the new road on the same turn?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in the [Almanac](http://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_5th_ed_rules_eng_150303.pdf) under "Building":

> You can build as many items and buy as many cards as you desire - as long as you have enough resources to "pay" for them and they are still available in the supply.

So as long as you have enough resources in hand, and roads available to you, you can build out as far as you like in one turn, and then add a settlement wherever you want to place it (while obeying the Distance Rule, of course).

I'd note that while the Turn Overview says for building a road, "place next to one of your settlements or cities", that cannot be correct since then you would never be able to build a second settlement (since you could never build a second road out to satisfy the Distance Rule).

Comment: I don't see that quote in your final paragraph in the "Turn Overview" part of the Almanac you linked to. Perhaps that's from an older version of the Almanac?

Comment: @Duncan The language in the Turn Overview under building roads is actually "A new road must always connect to 1 of your existing roads, settlements or cities." I think the entire last paragraph can probably be struck from this answer since it is tangential to the OP's question.

Comment: @SocioMatt - Yeah, I saw that quote. Not the same as what ConMan posted. I agree - it's not related to the original question so getting rid of it may be a good idea.

Comment: The turn overview is a separate document on the Catan website that shows a flowchart of a turn. I'll dig up the link ...

Comment: This one: http://www.catan.com/files/downloads/settlers_of_catan_turn_overview.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. You can build as many things as you want, as long as you can afford to and you're not breaking the rules. The game gives you this freedom while discouraging hoarding by threatening to take half of your resource cards when someone rolls a 7. Some people get lucky, they hoard tons of cards and then build 5 or 6 roads in a row -- all at once -- to steal the longest road. But this almost never happens. I've probably seen it once or twice, ever.